# What does the phrase "this the new vivy and millennium wavy" mean? Is it a slang?

Tags: terminology, slang, phrase-meaning

I was listening to the new Chris Brown's album, "Royalty" and the last track/song called "U Did It" which features the rapper Future has the following line that I didn't understand at all:

*I just need some codeine just to relax*
*This the new vivy and millennium, wavy*

This is the lyrics according to [Genius.com](http://genius.com/Chris-brown-u-did-it-lyrics) web site.

Also, I don't know what the words "vivy" and "millennium" mean, if someone could help me with that, I'd be grateful.

Comment: And what makes you think Genius.com has the lyrics correct? Most of these lyrics sites get some of them wrong.

Comment: @PeterShor it's basically maintained as a community like StackExchange

Comment: Yes, but there are tons of inaccurate lyrics at any of these sites (they get most of them right, but lyrics that are hard to hear are liable to be wrong).

Comment: @PeterShor But this part is pretty easy to be heard. I just want to know what's the meaning.

Comment: [A dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/) will tell you what 'millenium' means.

Comment: 'vivy' is not a word and the rest seems like nonsense (but could totally make sense if there were more context). In poetry and lyrics, anything goes. Maybe the author knows, or maybe he was making up sounds. That's art.

Comment: It's nonsense.  
    Mairzy doats and dozy doats and liddle lamzy divey
    A kiddley divey too, Wooden shoe?

Answer (score 1):

He is saying:

- **This the new *Vivian Millennium*, wavy**

Vivian's Millennium Cafe is a restaurant in LA, California.

I think he's trying to say "This place is the new Vivian Millennium," meaning "This is the new cool place to eat."

Why he says "wavy" at the end is probably solely (and lazily) to prime for the rhyme in the next line ("lately").

We can deduce that Chris Brown probably knows about this cafe, since Amber Rose (someone with whom Chris Brown associates) was spotted [there](http://www.celebuzz.com/photos/amber-rose-wears-a-waist-trainer-while-out-with-a-friend/amber-rose-122715-8/).

Everyone seems to have accepted "vivy and millenium" without thinking it through, despite it's ludicrousness.

Comment: Wavy is [slang](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wavy). And rap slang, at that. It seems to be the newest entry along the lines of *groovy, hip, neat, cool*.